# UDP socket programming HELP

Tags: ruby, sockets, lua, udp

I am looking for good tutorials on `UDP socket programming`. I have already googled, and I have not found any help through that, and so, I am posting it here. My basic goal is to read and write data on a remote machine through the UDP Port, and I would appreciate it if anyone could offer me some help / links to tutorials on that.

My ultimate goal is to code that in `Ruby` and/or `Lua`, but a tutorial in any language would be convenient to understand logic.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find this? <br>
https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/UDPSocket.html

Comment: Yes. I saw that. I am seeking a little more than that... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/03/ruby-udp-socket-example/